# Minimum transit time at Zürich airport

Tags: transit, zrh

I will fly with Swiss from Tel Aviv to Zürich, where I have a connecting flight with Swiss to Amsterdam. The layover lasts 1 hour and 25 minutes. Is that enough time to make this connection? Do I need to go through passport control and security?

Comment: Has this been sold to you as a single ticket?

Comment: You will be entering the Schengen Area in Zürich (and therefore will go through passport control there). The flight to Amsterdam will be an internal Schengen Area flight.

Answer (score 2):

> Is that enough time to make this connection?

If you bought this as a single ticket: yes.

If these are two separate tickets: no. I will assume that this is NOT the case and this is a single ticket.

To be precise: with a single ticket you have 90%+ chance of making this and in the unlikely case that you still miss it (due to no fault of your own), Swiss will rebook on the next flight to Amsterdam at no cost.

> Do I need to go through passport control

Yes. But your bags will get checked through to Amsterdam.

> and security?

No